# Codeigniter 2.1.3: sess_destroy() causes Undefined index: session_id etc notice when 'sess_use_database' == TRUE

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have been testing out the codeigniter's feature with sessions using database, and when ever I log out (use sess_destroy()) i get the following notices:

```
            A PHP Error was encountered

            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined index: session_id

            Filename: libraries/Session.php

            Line Number: 272
            A PHP Error was encountered

            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined index: ip_address

            Filename: libraries/Session.php

            Line Number: 272
            A PHP Error was encountered

            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined index: user_agent

            Filename: libraries/Session.php

            Line Number: 272
            A PHP Error was encountered

            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined index: last_activity

            Filename: libraries/Session.php

            Line Number: 272
            A PHP Error was encountered

            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined index: session_id

            Filename: libraries/Session.php

            Line Number: 288
            A PHP Error was encountered

            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined index: last_activity

            Filename: libraries/Session.php

            Line Number: 289
```

What do I need to do to fix that? (I know that I can turn off error reporting ect, but I am more interested to why this happens and how to fix it).

I used this to create the table:

```
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
                        session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
                        ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
                        user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
                        last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                        user_data text NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
                        KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
                );
```

The session lib is autoloaded.

Comment: Add a check before destroy .. if the session is set then destroy.

Comment: You can also test wether the session is working or not by setting and getting session value.

Comment: You can check if the session is working by simply calling print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); Since it sets some things by default there is no need to set a session variable before checking for the session. Since you say you're getting that on logout it looks like there is something in your code that is specifically trying to access a non-existent session. It's showing the errors in the session library because that is where they're occurring, it doesn't mean they aren't being created by a function in your application making a call it shouldn't be.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Show your config file and logout code and also make sure the table name is correct and check if there is any data in it.

Comment: @SachinPrasad I'm using https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth for the controller, you can find in that repo. And here is my autoload.php and config.php: https://gist.github.com/a41221961f49e4e75819

Answer (score 31):

This is causing your problem, with the release of 2.1.3:

> Fixed a bug (#1314) - Session Library method sess_destroy() didn't destroy the userdata array.

$this->tank_auth->logout() contains the function sess_destroy();
So after you have called this, you cannot use set_flashdata() in $this->_show_message().

What you need to do is create a new session. This is how your logout method should look like in auth.php:

```
/**
 * Logout user
 *
 * @return void
 */
function logout() {
    $this->tank_auth->logout(); // Destroys session
    $this->session->sess_create();
    $this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_logged_out'));
}
```

Comment: also an issue elsewhere in auth.php Search the rest of the file for "$this->tank_auth->logout();" and apply the above fix there too (currently hits reset_email(), and activate())

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a quick note to Ben's answer. He is correct in identifying the problem, but I found, because of the order of operations, it is more effective to add the create session line in the Tank_auth library.

Here is the revised logout() function in the Tank_auth.php library:

```
    /**
 * Logout user from the site
 *
 * @return  void
 */
function logout()
{
    $this->delete_autologin();

    // See http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/662369/ as the reason for the next line
    $this->ci->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' => ''));

    $this->ci->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->ci->session->sess_create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `application/config/config.php` file, and see if you have `$config[‘sess_use_database’] = TRUE`.

Comment: If you notice in the title I already said that the sess_use_database is enabled.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and my `sess_use_database` IS set to true. I STILL get the notices.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, refresh is what you are missing .
Have you tried redirect('logout', 'refresh');

Answer (score 0):

For Zach:
Since you are using Tank auth make sure your logout function is in this way:-

```
    function logout(){
        if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
            $this->tank_auth->logout();

            redirect('');           

        } 
    }
```

You can also autoload the most commonly used helpers and libraries :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation','pagination');
$autoload['helper'] = array('form','url','html');
```

Your config seems to be fine,may be you are trying to logout twice.If there is still issue please show your logout code.

Comment: I still get all the PHP security stuff... Here is my logout function: https://gist.github.com/cf9c5c875cb2d53112c9 And I'm just using the rest of the controller directly from: https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth/blob/master/application/controllers/auth.php

Is there a better user auth library that is more up-to-date and works for 2.1.3 better? I saw that Tank Auth was good but I didn't know if there was a better option? I'm starting from scratch here, so I'm not opposed to something else.